# "foreground" service is killed when App is removed from recent apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I have an App with a foreground service (which calls `startForeground`) which shows a notification. The notification is set to ongoing and updated by the service every second.

The service works perfectly fine in most devices, expect some of the devices from MI or Oppo. In those devices the service gets killed and notification is removed as soon as the app is removed from the recent tasks list.

From the Android documentation, a foreground service is not supposed to be killed just like that.

The AndroidManifest file lists the service as followed.

```
<service
    android:name=".IndicatorService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:stopWithTask="false"
    android:process=":background" />
```

As I said, I'm calling `startForeground` with a notification in `onStartCommand` in the Service. The `onStartCommand` returns `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`. I'm testing for Android 6+.

I know there are a number of questions around similar problem, but I could not find some satisfactory explanation and solution.

Specific questions.

1) Why is this happening in some devices?

2) What should be done to avoid a foreground service from being killed? What are some good/correct way to handle this?

Comment: any luck? to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope. Disabling "Battery optimisation" for the app sometimes helps.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think the underlying logic of removing a recent task has been changed on those MI or Oppo devices.

The documentation works for AOSP (and those passed CTS), but device vendors can customize Android in whatever way they want. They probably don't care about [Android Compatibility](https://source.android.com/compatibility/).